# While loop with "if" doesn't work properly

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I wasted hours thinking on why is this program working unproperly, without success. It always prints "The character is a special symbol".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
    char character;
    printf( "Please type any character and I will tell you what type it is:\n" );
while( 1 )
    {
        scanf( "%c", &character);
        if( character >= 65 && character <= 90 )
            printf( "The character is A-Z\n" );
        else if( character >= 97 && character <= 122 )
            printf( "The character is a-z\n" );
        else if( character >= 48 && character <= 57 )
            printf( "The character is 0-9\n" );
        else if(( character >= 0 && character <= 47 ) ||
                ( character >= 58 && character <= 64 ) ||
                ( character >= 91 && character <= 96 ) ||
                ( character >= 123 && character <= 127 ))
            printf( "The character is a special symbol\n" );
    }
}
```

RUN EXAMPLE

```
Please type any character and I will tell you what type it is:
4
The character is 0-9
The character is a special symbol
```

I've noticed it doesn't happen when I delete the while loop, but I don't understand why, I want that loop.

Comment: don't use scanf with a character instead use fgetc(stdin)

Comment: Because of the ugly way it works.    fgetc(stdin) does not suffer from the leading whitespace characters such as \n.   Sure it still gets them, but does no conversions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063879/fgetcstdin-in-a-loop-is-producing-strange-behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `scanf` should be like this:

```
    scanf(" %c", &character);
```

You are getting `The character is a special symbol` because `scanf` is also reading `\n`.

Comment: It has to have that space before the %, and it works! But I don't understand how :/ How should I google it? I already tried "[^\n]"

Comment: @user3646717: space before `%` will skip white space and reads the next character that is not white space.

Comment: `"%d"`, `"%s"`, `"%f"`, `" "`, etc. all consume leading white-space.  3 exceptions: `"%c"`, `"%["`, `"%n"`

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about that leading white-space!

Answer (score -3):

4 meets the condition to printf( "The character is a special symbol\n" );

Comment: No no ! It will print `The character is 0-9` as ASCII value of 4 is between 48 and 57