# undefined behaviour while using fgetc(stdin)

Tags: c, stdin, fgetc, fflush

Before asking this question, I have read: [fgetc(stdin) in a loop is producing strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063879/fgetcstdin-in-a-loop-is-producing-strange-behaviour). I am writing a program to ask the user if they want to exit. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int ask_to_exit()
{
    int choice;
    while(choice!='y'||choice!='n')
    {   printf("Do you want to continue?(y/n):");
        while((fgetc(stdin)) != '\n');
        choice = fgetc(stdin);
        if(choice=='y') return 0;
        else if(choice=='n') return 1;
        else printf("Invalid choice!\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int exit = 0;
    while(!exit)
    {
        exit = ask_to_exit();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since fflush(stdin) is undefined behaviour, I did not use it. After following the solution in the other question, I still get the error. Here is a test run of the above program:

```
$./a.out
Do you want to continue?(y/n):y<pressed enter key>
<pressed enter key>
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):y<pressed enter key>
<pressed enter key>
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):n<pressed enter key>
<pressed enter key>
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):n<pressed enter key>
n<pressed enter key>
<program exits>
```

Comment: Using `choice` variable without initializing it!

Comment: does that matter?? I am checking with while(choice!='y'||choice!='n') , so even if it is not initialized ,it will not be 'y' or 'n',so it should work,right??

Comment: `do... while()` loop is more appropriate for such cases, instead of `while` loop.

Comment: Yes it matters. Using a local variable without initializing is undefined behavior

Comment: even after using do...while() loop, it has the same error.

Comment: `choice!='y'||choice!='n'` is *always* true. If it is one, it can't possibly be the other. If it is neither, still true. If it is *both*, call your university astrophysics department, because you've discovered a worm hole.

Comment: Your loop discards all the input and keeps the `\n`

Comment: yes, as stated by Stephen Dorcy.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the first time through the loop, choice has not been initialised so its value is indeterminate. And an indeterminate value might compare equal to `'y`'` and then immediately compare equal to `'n'`. No astrophysics required; see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_260.htm

Comment: ok I got the point.

Comment: Note that the choice of `exit` as the name for a variable isn't a particularly good idea.  It means you can no longer call the function of that name in the function where you define the variable.  It isn't technically wrong; it is ill-advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get some input before checking the value of `choice` or it will be uninitialized. And also, you are draining the left-over input before grabbing the first character, you should do it after:

```
int ask_to_exit()
{
    int choice;

    do
    {
        printf("Do you want to continue?(y/n):");
        choice = fgetc(stdin);

        while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');

        if (choice == 'y') {
            return 0;
        } else if (choice == 'n') {
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid choice!\n");
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

ouput:

```
Do you want to continue?(y/n):g
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):h
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):j
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):k
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):m
Invalid choice!
Do you want to continue?(y/n):y
Do you want to continue?(y/n):y
Do you want to continue?(y/n):y
Do you want to continue?(y/n):n
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: That `||` should be `&&`.

Comment: after changing || to && it has still the same problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig...true that is the correct logic, though since both `y` and `n` cause the function to return, a simple `true` for the while check would actually be best

Comment: Check this:https://ideone.com/LFCbwn. It's the same code you suggested.Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try my exact code or did you just modify yours to match mine?  Maybe you forgot to move the `while (fgetc(stdin)...` code to after `choice = fgetc(stdin);`

Comment: Sorry I just had forgot to put n in the input. Thanks!

Comment: sorry but it still has the same problem and I just pasted your code.

Comment: Hmmm, it works fine for me, specifically how is your code failing?

Comment: it works in my computer but fails in the online ide. You can check this yourself:https://ideone.com/LFCbwn.Anyways sorry for any trouble.

Comment: Quite possibly because it looks like the language is set to `C++` in the ide?

Comment: might be but since there was no option to change it, I didn't knew it was set to c++.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the issue or not.  I threw the code in a cpp file in Visual Studio and it still worked fine.  Might be some weird behavior with respect to how the ide is feeding the input to the program.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems in your code.

1. You are using `choice` before initializing it.
2. You are skipping a line of input before reading anything into `choice`.

Error noticed by @WhozCraig:

`choice!='y'||choice!='n'` is always true.

I suggest:

```
int ask_to_exit()
{
   int choice;
   while ( 1 )
   {
      printf("Do you want to continue?(y/n):");
      choice = fgetc(stdin);
      if ( choice == 'y' )
      {
         return 0;
      }
      if ( choice == 'n' )
      {
         return 1;
      }

      printf("Invalid choice!\n");

      // Skip rest of the line.
      int c;`
      while( (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');

      // If EOF is reached, return 0 also.
      if ( c == EOF )
      {
         return 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The return values are ok, `0` is returned for `y`, which makes `while(!exit)` true, and so the program continues.  Returning `1` for `n` causes `while(!exit)` to be false, and the program exits.